# BackupAgent has one cloud backup per Device?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have one Google Account with many devices attached (look in settings of market website). When I backup my App with `BackupAgent` and wipe another device, the wiped device doesn't restore anything. If I save a text "Nexus S" on one device and "Nexus One" on another one, they restore "Nexus S" and "Nexus One".

It is the normal behavior? Can we use `BackupAgent` with an unique backup as iCloud allow?

Comment: did you figure this out? I know it's been a while ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is tied to the user's Google Account. When a user send a data from a device. It is stored and when the user installs the app from the store to a new device the last data is restored. 
If you want to do different data on different devices, you have to make some sort of syncing mechanism using sync adapter or something.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case. I am testing it on two devices I am logged in on with my account. They both show only the data they stored themselves, like Ellis says